# Date format and Array which uses menu-based program

Tags: java

How do I make a Hindi language date format using the locale class in Java? And, second question, how do I make a bank account using an array for loop in a menu-based program in Java ?

Comment: You need to make your questions more specific - see http://tinyurl.com/so-hints. Also, ask one question per post.

Comment: Also see this video by Jon Skeet [on how to get what you need from forums](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kzrz-hGr2bw).

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet should help you with the first question.

`new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", new Locale("hi", "IN"));`

The second one is not specific enough.